# Amazon s3 storing videos then output it in my site

Tags: php, javascript, amazon-s3

I'm building a site that has a video uploading. I want all the videos to be stored in Amazon S3. How would I do that? I can't find any link regarding my issue.

Maybe there is a sample code on how to implement this one, including fetching all the videos that has been uploaded in Amazon S3

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated and rewarded.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the [Amazon Web Services PHP SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/). 
I would suggest downloading the SDK and read the [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/). 
To upload an object to a bucket you use the [`create_object`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/create_object) API ,to get the list of objects stored you would use [get_object_list](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/get_object_list) and to get the contents of a specific object you would use [get_object](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/get_object).

Cheers,
Shai.